Syntax error when running file created with Save which contains backslashes
I am doing a nested integration. So far the result was successfully saved with Save["filename.wl", IntOutput] and looked as following:
{8.699216412022851*^-8, 8.70971945796472*^-8, 
     8.724312065608903*^-8, 8.739384913073602*^-8, 8.751210081392647*^-8, 
     8.756863232442175*^-8, 8.754946986080317*^-8}

Now I have a fast oscillating term added and I increase precision with WorkingPrecision->22. Using the same Save function, the content of filename.wl is now:
{8.699216412022879139524462907795`21.69897000433602*^-8, 
     8.70971945796480158227693635290900000000000000000001`21.69897000433602*^\
-8, 
     8.72431206560898340384359591002399999999999999999999`21.69897000433602*^-8\
, 8.739384913073543185225410529993`21.698970004336026*^-8, 
     8.751210081392679873974725075826`21.69897000433602*^-8, 
     8.756863232442135389693899773939`21.69897000433602*^-8}

When I open this file and try to evalute it, contrary to the previous successful tries, I get the syntax error: 
What might be the case? How can I fix this syntax error and what might be the origins?
UPD To reproduce the issue (I am using Mathematica 13.0.1):

Initialize an array:

IntOutput={8.699216412022879139524462907795`21.69897000433602*^-8,8.70971945796480158227693635290900000000000000000001`21.69897000433602*^-8,8.72431206560898340384359591002399999999999999999999`21.69897000433602*^-8,8.739384913073543185225410529993`21.698970004336026*^-8,8.751210081392679873974725075826`21.69897000433602*^-8,8.756863232442135389693899773939`21.69897000433602*^-8}


Run

Save["filename.wl", IntOutput]


Open filename.wl and Run it.

I checked, the error is reproducible for me with these steps.

Please look at Precision and Control the Precision and Accuracy of Numerical Results.

Thank you, updated my post  erasing part with " " ` " symbol"

So are you still confused by the backtick ` or about the backslash \? Backslash is used to break long lines.

Thank you I am less confused now, but it does not help to solve the issue I faced with. When running filename.wl I get the syntax error see image I attached to head post. I am confused now even more. What might be the source of the syntax error and why Save function started to save it in the such awkward format ?

Don't copy&paste the contents of the file. Simply use Get["filename.wl"].

I might misunderstand the point of your comment now.
The format given in image is the original format of  how Save function saved the file, I have just opened it to run. However despite it is saved as a list I can not run it to initialize as IntOutput.

@seva011 the point is, to get back what you saved using Save command, you need to use Get command from inside Mathematica. You are not meant to open it using texteditor or copy paste it using the mouse.

I am sorry for bothering you. I need to comment to this. I do Save for several lists, such that filename.wl looks like:
A={a1, a2, ..., a800};
B={b1, b2, ..., b800};
B={c1, c2, ..., c800};```
Calculations are done on a cluster and this is the way I use to get my data stored so far.

When evalute `filename.wl` I simply get lists A,B,C  on my PC. 

With the function `Get` you propose I only get as an output {a1, a2, ..., a800}. No lists B and C.

If possible I would prefer to understand why `Save` saves lists in such awkward way, adding "new line" in between some numbers.

No. When you issue  Get on a file, you go get the full definitions back of all the variables. Mathematica just prints the value of A (i.e. the right side). But if you do ?A then you will see it there after you do Get, even in new session.

If you used Matlab, Save and Get are similar to Matlab's commands save and load

I can not reproduce your problem. I get correct results with both versions of your IntOutput (without using Get just straight  opening the file) I have version 13.0, what is your version?

Gentleman I have added the way to reproduce the error I got (Mathematica 13.0.1).
@Nasse, please check whether you have another output.

Yes, I get same output you show using V 14 on windows. The \\`` is there. This is because Save does not use PageWidth->Infinityby default. But again, this does not affect the content if it is read using theGetcommand. Savedoes not acceptPageWidth->Infinity` option. Only stream output does. There might be an option in preferences to change  this. I do not know.

@Domen Now I got your point. Thank you ! It helped me and it is way to convenient to handle.  I will resort to your suggestion.
Nonetheless, the issue with evaluation the file directly is still exist.

@ Nasser Thank you for the suggestion to use Get, given together with Domen.
Thank you also for commenting on the origin of the issue.

@Nasser It is a bug. The problem is not "" but I think its position within the number because if you do the same with N[{Sqrt[1/17777777777777]}, 1000] there are several "" and works fine with Save and running the opened file with it.

@Nasser out = N[{Sqrt[1/17777777777777]}, 1000]; Save["file.wl", out]

Dear @azerbajdzan, there is "new line" separator in between some numbers, it has no "", see screenshot. Formally, this can be named the error. But the origin was suggested by Nasser above, concerning the PageWidth option of Save which is not accepted.

@seva011 Your comment does not make sense to me. There is evidently "" in screenshot. And it is put in a wrong place by Save. It is evident bug of Save.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Nasser, Save uses OpenAppend, which accepts PageWidth, so you can do SetOptions[OpenAppend, PageWidth -> Infinity] and it works also for Save :)

TL;DR: It's not a bug, you are just using the functionality incorrectly.

As I have already mentioned in the comments, in my opinion, this is not a bug. I suggest you read the tech note on Reading and Writing Wolfram System Files, where you can see that there are several ways of storing Wolfram Language expressions in external files.
The main idea is that you store the expression in a file, then use Get to load the expression back into the Wolfram Session. If you use this approach, everything works as expected, and there is no syntax error. You are not meant to open this file in a front-end and expect that it should be executable just because it looks like it should be! For example, besides Save, there is also DumpSave, which saves definitions for a symbol in internal Wolfram Language format. If you open this file in a front-end and evaluate the cell, it will obviously not work.
@azerbajdan has a very funny argument in the comments below his answer. He claims that since there is a "Run All Code" button, the code should be runnable. This is of course a non-sense. Mathematica front-end is in its basic form a text-editor, and you can open any file you want with it. Let's say you do:
Export["file", "+*'*-=", "Text"]

and open the file in Mathematica.

Look, there is a red "Evaluate" button in the top-left! But when you click it, you will get back syntax errors. Are you surprised by this? Is this a bug? I hope it's obvious that this is not a bug. The same goes with using Save and the .wl format that is used.

In the tech note I linked above, you can also find an answer on why these backslashes appear when you do Save. It is the PageWidth (as mentioned by @Nasser) which is used when writing to the file stream. You can simulate the same behaviour with:
out = N[1/10^(25/2), 54];
Export["file", FullDefinition[out], "WL", PageWidth -> 20];
FilePrint["file"]

(* Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com *)
out = 3.16227766016\
8379331998893544432\
7185337195551393252\
168268575048528`54.\
*^-13 

If you really want, you can change the PageWidth used in Save by setting it on the OpenAppend, which is used inside Save:
SetOptions[OpenAppend, PageWidth -> Infinity];
Save["file2", out]
FilePrint["file2"]

out = 3.1622776601683793319988935444327185337195551393252168268575048528`54.*^-13


To conclude, use Save together with Get to store and load the definitions of your symbols. However, if you want to save your results in a format which is compatible with using Mathematica front-end, you have to use some other approach.

My argument is not as funny is your argument with Export["file", "+*'*-=", "Text"].  What is it supposed to prove? If you type in code with errors then how you expect it should work without errors? Contrary with you, me and OP have given examples of correct code that produces incorrect result that is caused by a bug in Save. That is all. What  is incomprehensible about it?

Gentleman, I would suggest to wait for the comments from technical support. My original confusion was exact as azerbajdzan described. Domen's explanation and pointing at 'Get' perfectly works to me. Nevertheless, I would summarize, this polemics with the following question: Should running WL script bottom be of the same meaning as a 'Get' function ? (please correct me if I interpret wrong). If the answer is yes, then it is indeed can be sort of a bug or discrepancy. Otherwise it is just a feature of the Save/Get functions, and WL file should not be treated as rude as I used it prior.

Save should be able to save files correctly regardless of PageWidth.  What a nonsense it is to avoid some numbers because we are using PageWidth->78. ".wl" file is like ".m" file and when opened it must be runnable the more that the content was created automatically and not by hand. Suppose you have some large ".wl" file and want to edit it. So you open it in Mathematica and then have to spend a day by correcting errors that were caused by Save. ".wl" file is definitely not only feature of the Save/Get.

@three777, again, Save makes no errors, and you can edit its content and it will still work when you use Get. If you need to manually edit the output file, just don't use Save, because this is not its purpose. It's as simple as that :)

COMMENT from SUPPORT: "The file you mention is a .wl (Wolfram Language) plain text file and not a notebook file. As the Stack Exchange case suggests use Get to read the contents f the file into the kernel. BackSlash characters () ae escape characters used in plain text files to indicate things such as line returns. The program appears to be working as designed. I can see NO reason to assume there is any kind of bug here."

@seva011, thanks for letting us know and confirm that there is indeed no bug.

It is a bug and should be reported to Wolfram.
Save puts \ in a wrong place for some numbers as can be seen in the first file.
In the second file we see that \ was placed in an allowed position and no error occurs on executing the code.
out = N[1/10^(25/2), 54];
Save["file1.wl", out]

out = N[1/10^(25/2), 55];
Save["file2.wl", out]





Why would this be a bug? .wl files exported via Save are supposed to be used via Get, and this works fine. They are not notebooks, so there is no need for them to be runnable in a notebook. Using your logic, why don't you then use DumpSave to save a file in binary, then open it via frontend and complain that it does not run and there is a bug?

@Domen No. You can work with .wl file like you can do with .nb file or .m file or any other file that Mathematica supports. It is not meant to be used only by Get. You totally miss the point of OP question as can be seen also from your comments below OP question.

@Domen Have you ever had opened a .wl file? Probably not because there is a button Run All Code. Why do they in Wolfram put such a button on the window of .wl file? Not so easy to understand for people that think "they have a patent on reason", or "they know-it-all".

@azerbajdzan, I sent a request  to Support, asking them to take a look over this thread. I agree with you, and believe you got my (OP's) point. Till any comments from Support I will use proposed Get function to handle with lists.
